# How to merge two objects in C#  asp.net mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two objects declared like so:

```
new {@class = "aClass", bar="bar"}
```

and

```
new{foo = "foo"}
```

How do i combine them so i get this result?

```
{@class = "aClass", bar="bar", foo = "foo"}
```

(in any order)

My goal is to combine extra html attributes in a custom htmlhelper.

Cheers

Comment: What do you expect to happen if they contain duplicates (meaning both collections contain the same property)?

Comment: Haven't really thought about it because i don't expect it to happen. But thats a very good point. I guess I'll have to override it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
object x = new { @class = "aClass", bar = "bar" };
object y = new { foo = "foo" };

var htmlAttributes = new RouteValueDictionary(x);
foreach (var item in new RouteValueDictionary(y))
{
    htmlAttributes[item.Key] = item.Value;
}

// at this stage htmlAttributes represent an IDictionary<string, object>
// that will contain the 3 values and which could be passed
// along to the overloaded versions of the standard helpers 
// for example:
var link = htmlHelper.ActionLink("link text", "foo", null, htmlAttributes);

// would generate:
// <a href="/home/foo" class="aClass" bar="bar" foo="foo">link text</a>
```

Comment: Fantastic answer! Exactly what i needed. Can i just query, what will happen if both objects contain a property of the same name?

Comment: @MrJD, the second will prevail and overwrite the first. But if this is not something that you desire inside the foreach loop you could test whether a key is present in the htmlAttributes dictionary before overwriting it.

Comment: That functionality is fine. I just didn't want any exceptions thrown. Thanks!

Comment: This didn't work for me - but an answer to a similar question elsewhere did the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188570/add-to-htmlattributes-for-custom-actionlink-helper-extension

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want is to merge 2 anonymous objects.
This question is about that subject:

[Is there an easy way to merge C# anonymous objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130367/is-there-an-easy-way-to-merge-c-sharp-anonymous-objects?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two objects are of anonymous types

```
var a = new { @class = "aClass", bar = "bar" };
var b = new { foo = "foo" };
```

the only way to combine them is to create a new object that has the members of both of them:

```
var result = new { a.@class, a.bar, b.foo };
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: That would be good, except i don't have the definition for the first class. So i can't select it's properties.