# Composable LINQ Select Clause

Tags: linq, anonymous-types

Is there a way to build on to the select clause of a previously defined LINQ query?

For example:

```
var stuffQuery =
    from stuff in MyStuff
    select new {
        stuff.Name
    };
var query2 =
    from stuff in stuffQuery
    join otherStuff in YourStuff on stuff.Name equals otherStuff.Name
    select new {
        stuff.*, // how can I accomplish this?
        YourStuff = new {
            otherStuff.PropertyX
        }
    };
```

The result I want is an object like:

```
string Name
anonymous YourStuff
        string PropertyX
```

I thought about using a "[Combine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130367/is-there-an-easy-way-to-merge-c-sharp-anonymous-objects)" method which would reflectively combine my two anonymous objects into a dynamic.  But Linq-to-Sql won't know what to do with the method.

Instead, I think I need a method which returns the select expression.  Its parameters would be the first Queryable, and the select expression for the second Queryable.  Something like:

```
var query2 =
    from stuff in stuffQuery
    join otherStuff in YourStuff on stuff.Name equals otherStuff.Name
    GetCombinedSelectClause(stuffQuery, new {
        YourStuff = new {
            otherStuff.PropertyX
        }
    });
```

How can I accomplish this?  I'm not married to any particular syntax-style.  However, I'd prefer not to use a string-based solution (such as System.Linq.Dynamic).

Comment: Are you saying you don't want to hard-code the field names in the Select statement?

Comment: I want two separate queries.  I want to combine these two queries into one.  I want the contents of the first select clause to sit side-by-side with the contents of the second select clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question probably isn't worded the best it could be.  However, I do not think LINQ queries were designed to accomplish the goal I was after.

I'm closing the question because I simply do not think the answer is achievable.

Answer (score 0):

How about [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? I believe it can do exactly what you need.

Comment: Did you have a chance to try it?